# Debugging a simple client and server program

Tags: java, client-server

in the following code, i am implementing a basic server client dice game. however, the client scanner does not seem to be reading anything

ServerClass:

```
public class ServerClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3300);
        System.out.println("Server started on port " + server.getLocalPort() + " and " + server.getInetAddress());

        while (true) {
            Socket client = server.accept();

            ClientHandler clientHandle = new ClientHandler(client);
            Thread thread = new Thread(clientHandle);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Client class:

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        Socket server = new Socket("localhost", 3300);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader input;
        PrintWriter output;
        int clientDice;
        int serverDice;

        try {
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
            output = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true);

            System.out.println(input.readLine());

            String playing = "play";
            while ("play".equals(playing)) {
                System.out.println(input.readLine());
                playing = scanner.nextLine();
                output.println(playing);
                if ("play".equals(playing)) {
                    serverDice = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
                    clientDice = new Random().nextInt(6);
                    System.out.println("Client rolled " + clientDice + ". Server rolled " + serverDice);
                } else {
                    playing = "exit";
                }
            }
            server.close();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ClientHandler class:

```
public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
    public Socket client;

    public ClientHandler(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public void run() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader input;
        PrintWriter output;
        int serverDice;

        try {
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

            System.out.println("New client connected");
            System.out.println("Server is ready to play");

            String playing = "play";
            while ("play".equals(playing)) {
                output.println("Would you like to play?");
                playing = input.readLine();
                if ("play".equals(playing)) {
                    output.println(new Random().nextInt(6));
                }
            }
            client.close();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

i entered "play" nothing happened, it doesnt even recogonize the input

Comment: The issue here is clearly just the order of input/output operations on both the client and the server side. @Progman's answer contains good tips.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You should check the chronological order of events at the server and client and when they read or write data. When a client is connected to the server, the server will send the string "Would you like to play?" via

```
output.println("Would you like to play?");    /* server */
```

to the client. After that it will wait with

```
playing = input.readLine();                   /* server */
```

for any response from the client. On the client side it will read and print a message from the server with the line

```
System.out.println(input.readLine());        /* client */
```

The client will read and print the initial "Would you like to play?" message from the server. But after that, inside the `while()` loop, it will read for any *additional* data from the server with

```
System.out.println(input.readLine());       /* client */
```

again. Since the server is waiting for input from the client and not sending any data and the client is waiting for input from the server and not sending any data, both participants are waiting for input from the other side, but none of them are sending anything. This results in a deadlock.

You might want to add additional info/debug lines to check what the client and server are doing at which point in time. As an example you could write

```
System.out.println("[debug] Going to read data from the server");
System.out.println(input.readLine());
System.out.println("[debug] Read of data complete");
```

and

```
System.out.println("[debug] Going to send the data '"+playing+"' to the server");
output.println(playing);
System.out.println("[debug] Send of data complete");
```

The solution to your problem might be as easy as removing the line

```
System.out.println(input.readLine());
```

from above the `while` loop since you already read data inside the `while` loop